# JQuery Calls Itself Recursively

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table that shows userid, name, internetstatus, button

If internet status is 0, when I click on the button it will update the database as 1 and vice versa.

Also `row['internet'] == 0 //Red button` and `row['internet'] == 1 //Green button`. When I click on Red Button `internet's` value will be changed to `1` and and vice versa.

[image: Table Example Image]

Everything works as intended. The only problem is, when I click on `User #2`'s button (according to image), it will also affect `User #3` and both will be updated. If they all have the same status, then all will be updated instead of only clicked one.

What part should I fix to code work as intended?

Main Page:

```
...table code...
//If internet == 0, Red Button will display
if($row['internet'] == 0) {
echo "<td><button type='submit' style='width:100%' class='btn btn-danger'  value='ariza' id='".$row['id']."'>Problem</button></td>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
            var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
            var kullanici = ".$row['id'].";
            var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
                data = {
                    'action': clickBtnValue,
                    'kullanici': kullanici
                };
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                // Changes
                $('#ariza').removeClass('btn-danger');
                $('#ariza').addClass('btn-success');
                $('#ariza').html('Düzeltildi');
                $('#var').html('Arızalı');
                $('#var').css('color', 'red');
                alert(response);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    location.reload();
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    });
</script>";
// If internet == 1, Green Button will display
} else {
echo "<td><button type='submit' style='width:100%' class='btn btn-success'  value='duzelt' id='".$row['id']."'>OK</button></td>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn-success').click(function() {
            var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
            var kullanici = ".$row['id'].";
            var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
                data = {
                    'action': clickBtnValue,
                    'kullanici': kullanici
                };
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                // Changes
                $('#duzelt').removeClass('btn-success');
                $('#duzelt').addClass('btn-danger');
                $('#duzelt').html('Arızalı');
                $('#yok').html('Var');
                $('#yok').css('color', 'green');
                alert(response);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    location.reload();
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    });
</script>";
}
```

ajax.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'duzelt':
            isaretle_arizali();
            break;
        case 'ariza':
            isaretle_duzeltildi();
            break;
    }
}
```

Functions.php:

```
function isaretle_arizali()
    {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $content = $_POST['kullanici'];
    $int = 0;
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET internet=? WHERE id=?"))
        {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $int, $content);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        echo "Marked as Problem";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Fail.";
        }
    }

function isaretle_duzeltildi()
    {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $content = $_POST['kullanici'];
    $int = 1;
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET internet=? WHERE id=?"))
        {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $int, $content);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        echo "Marked as Fixed";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Fail.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you have multiple buttons with the same ID #ariza - dont do this. Also you need to be looking at $this.class() to only change the button that is clicked, rather than changing all buttons with the same class (or ID in your case I think)

Comment: @Theavonguy Every button has an `id` of its `userid` (`id='".$row['id']`). Basically when I click on User3's button, its ID is unique and should only update User3's. But I must be missing something. Edit* I see what you ment, I am updating it to see if it works!

Comment: if that doesnt work, can you edit the post to include the html output please?

Comment: You are binding the same selector multiple times using a different function body. You'll end up calling all of them. instead of `$(".btn-danger")` bind by `$(<?=$row["id"]?>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution which would also minimize code duplication. Put this JavaScript code only once.

Note again. Only put this JavaScript code in your page once. You don't need to put it in more times as it works depending on what is clicked.

**Example PHP code**

```
//...table code...
//If internet == 0, Red Button will display
if($row['internet'] == 0): ?>
    <td>
       <button type='submit' style='width:100%' class='btn btn-danger'  value='ariza' id='<?=$row['id']?>'>Problem</button>
    </td>
<?php else: ?>
         <td>
            <button type='submit' style='width:100%' class='btn btn-success'  value='duzelt' id='<?=$row['id']?>'>OK</button>
        </td>
<?php endif; 

   // Rest of PHP code?

?>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn-success, .btn-danger').click(function() {
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var kullanici = $(this).attr("id");
        var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
        var data = {
            'action': clickBtnValue,
            'kullanici': kullanici
        };
        var self = this;
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            // Changes
            if ($(self).is(".btn-success")) {
                  $(self).removeClass('btn-success'); 
                  $(self).addClass('btn-danger');
                  $(self).html('Arızalı');
                  $(self).parent().prev().html('Var');
                  $(self).parent().prev().css('color', 'green');
            } else {
                $(self).removeClass('btn-danger');
                $(self).addClass('btn-success');
                $(self).html('Düzeltildi');        
                $(self).parent().prev().html('Arızalı');
                $(self).parent().prev().css('color', 'red');
            }

            alert(response);
            setTimeout(function() {
                location.reload();
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a great explanation! `var data` should be `data` I assume. I updated my solution regarding to this one. Wow, too much duplicate code I had :-) Only thing is, buttons won't be updated. Text is updating but only first column's :)

Comment: @MesutK if there is a reason to declare data as globally available then yes, otherwise I don't see why you can't use `var data`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the selectors in the ajax success function. Updated now, it should probably work.

Comment: Oh I see! I really appreciate for your helps, I sure learned a lot and realized how badly I wrote this code at start. :-)